# Problema para modificar una variable con Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un problema con Vue js:
Trato de hacer algo así como una lista de notas.
Tengo un array de json donde se guardaran todas las notas y un json donde se guarda la nota que la persona quiere crear. Pero el problema es:

Luego de hacer un push a el array de json se agrega perfectamente pero luego al modificar el valor en el json se modifica automáticamente el array de json.

No puedo modificar el json sin que me modifique el valor en el array.
PD: el método que hace el push se activa cuando hago click a un button

Dejaré aquí el código mas relevante, si necesitan mas información con mucho gusto la brindare.

```
el: '#app',
    data: {
        hasError: 0,
        typeError: '',
        noteSelected: null,
        note: {
            title: '',
            content: '',
            tags: [],
            tagsString: ''
        },
        notes: [{
            title: 'titulo de una nota',
            content: 'contenido de una nota',
            tags: ['nota', 'contenido'],
            tagsString: ''
        }]
    },
   methods:{
      newNote: function() {
            if (this.validate() === true && this.noteSelected === null) {
                this.addTags();
                this.noteSelected = this.note;
                this.notes.push(noteSelected);
            }
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El asunto no es con Vue.js, es con Javascript.

En Javascript (y otros lenguajes) sucede algo curioso: *los argumentos de tipo complejo son pasados por referencia y los primitivos por valor*. Los arreglos `clave -> valor` en Javascript (siendo objetos/JSON) son de tipo complejos, por ende, sus valores se pasan como referencia. (Referencia al indice en memoria).

**¿Que tiene que ver esto con tu problema?**

Todo.

**Entonces ¿Por que sucede esto?**

Al que copiar el valor de `this.note` a `this.noteSelected` con una igualdad (`this.noteSelected = this.note`) y luego haciendo un `array.push()` al objeto `this.notes` no se pasa el valor de un objeto a otro si no una referencia al indice de memoria donde esta dicho valor. Al intentar modificar el valor en alguno de estos se modifica el valor en el espacio en memoria y por eso se ve como si se modificase en ambos arrays.

**Blablabla ¿y la solución es?**

Puedes utilizar un pequeño "*hack*" para obtener el valor y no la referencia del objeto convirtiéndolo en un `String` con `JSON.stringify()` y luego de nuevo a un objeto `json` con `JSON.parse()` (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON))`)

En tu caso quedaría así:

```
newNote: function() {
  if (this.validate() === true && this.noteSelected === null) {
    this.addTags();
    this.noteSelected = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.note)); // <- Aquí el cambio: 
    this.notes.push(noteSelected);
  }
},
```

Otra solución, si tienes una instancia de **jQuery** sería utilizar la función `jQuery.extend()` lo cual sería casi igual, solo que la linea en cuestión quedaría asi: `this.noteSelected = jQuery.extend({}, this.note);`

Aquí dejo un link al jsbin reproduciendo el "fenómeno" que ocurre https://jsbin.com/yiwuvuruzi/edit?js,console

No es complejo de entender, tiene su lógica aunque es algo confuso. Espero que resuelva tu problema, y mas aun, que aclare tu confusión.